# I can't get a clear idea of the meaning of the enum commentary in Dart's official documentation

Tags: dart, enums

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types

> Abstract classes and mixins can explicitly implement or extend Enum,
> but unless they are then implemented by or mixed into an enum
> declaration, no objects can actually implement the type of that class
> or mixin.

No matter how many times I read this part, I can't understand the meaning and I can't imagine it with concrete code.

Anyone who knows, can you tell me what this sentence specifically says?

Is this a description of enum's new feature?

Comment: It means you can do `abstract class A extends Enum {}` and `enum B implements A { a, b, c }` but not `class C extends A {}` or `class D extends Enum {}`.

Comment: You will have to use dart version `2.17.0` or higher. You can set the dart sdk version in your `pubspec.yaml` file, you may need to also run `flutter upgrade` if your dart installation is bundled with flutter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
When I tried it with version 2.17.3 of Dartpad, A and B had no error, and C and D had an error.
I'm going to think based on this.